# JNI: How to delete a local reference c++

Tags: android, c++, reference, java-native-interface, local

For improving the performance of my android app i decided to re write calculation parts in c++ and use JNI. here is the problem :

My c++ method generates very large amount of objects (2k to 10k) in a multiple level loop. An object is being created in the deepest level and stored in a vector of jobject's for the later return. My implementation of the last part is as below:

```
jobject genObj = env->NewObject(jclass,jmethodId,...);
Vector.push_back(genObj);
env->DeleteLocalRef(genObj);
```

this code gives me:

***JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference***

Which means im trying to access a deleted block of memory. This is unexpected because push_back should copy the argument not its pointer.

What should i do ?

Ps: not deleting the local ref will lead to localref table overflow

Answer (score 2):

You could create global references of your objects using `NewGlobalRef` put those in the vector, then delete the local references. This way you can keep your objects in a vector as long as you don't run out of memory. Make sure you don't forget to delete those global references with `DeleteGlobalRef` once you don't need them anymore, because the garbage collector doesn't collect objects held in native memory.

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#referencing_java_objects)

Answer (score 1):

OYou're saving the local reference in `Vector,` deleting it, but then using it out of `Vector` later on. You can't do that. You can't delete it until you're really finished with it.

Maybe you should look into `PushLocalFrame()` and friends if you're running out of local references.

Or use a Java collection instead of the C++ `Vector`.

Comment: I don't know what the point of your vector is. Only you know that. And I didn't say anything another keeping both. I've given you two ways, that's enough for one day.